# HTTP Error when trying to insert csv file from a url to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, http, pymongo

I'm trying to send data from a csv file to mongodb using a python insertion script. I have to get this file directly via url, that is, it is not local. I'm using pymongo and read_csv from pandas to do the insertion, but I'm getting an "***HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error***". I imagine it is something related to encoding or header. I have tried several combinations, but none have worked. Here is the code:

```
try:
    import pymongo
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import pandas as pd
    import json
except Exception as e:
    print("Some Modules are Missing ")

import requests
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError


class MongoDB(object):

    def __init__(self, dBName=None, collectionName=None):

        self.dBName = dBName
        self.collectionName = collectionName

        #self.client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        self.client = MongoClient("<connection_string>")

        self.DB = self.client[self.dBName]
        self.collection = self.DB[self.collectionName]



    def InsertData(self, path=None):

        df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=";", encoding='UTF-8', header="infer")
        data = df.to_dict('records')

        self.collection.insert_many(data, ordered=False)
        print("All the Data has been Exported to Mongo DB Server .... ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mongodb = MongoDB(dBName = 'vacinacao-covid', collectionName='teste')
    mongodb.InsertData(path = "https://www.saopaulo.sp.gov.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/20210420_percentual_primeira_dose.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 does not work on my end. I used latin-1 instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO


user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
path = "https://www.saopaulo.sp.gov.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/20210420_percentual_primeira_dose.csv"
r = requests.get(path, headers=user_agent)
f = BytesIO(r.content)
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", encoding='latin-1', header="infer")
print(df)
```